# How to save data from an array

Tags: c#

I'm making a simple application to save school grades and displays it back to you when requested. How can I save this data so you do not have to reenter it every time the application is run?

Comment: The simplest way is to store them in a text file in cvs format. It can be just some unique identifier of the student, like fac id and the grade.

Comment: Is this winforms or asp, or console?

Comment: Where is your code? What kind of application is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split problem into *lesser* ones:

- How would you like to *save* an item *to* `string` in a file
- How would you like to *read* (*parse*) an item *from* a `string` (line) of the file?

in case *school grades* are just `int`s:

```
int[] grades = new int[] {2, 3, 4, 5, 2};
```

the answers for the questions above can be `item.ToString()` and `int.Parse(line)` and so you can put

```
File
  .WriteAllLines(@"C:\MyData.txt", grades
  .Select(grade => grade.ToString()));
```

And

```
int[] grades = File
  .ReadLines(@"C:\MyData.txt")
  .Select(line => int.Parse(line))
  .ToArray();
```